# How can I detect LocallApStore tool on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, jailbreak

How can I detect `LocallApStore` tool on the iPhone? Also the same question for `iApFree` and `iApCracker`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for this thing you have to detect it's dylib.
By calling

```
NSString *dylibPath = @"/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibrares/LocalIAPStore.dylib";
BOOL fileExiste = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExiste
sAtPath:dylibPath];
If (fileExiste) {
    NSLog (@"existe");
}
```

and others you have to detect there dylibs too,
Good luck

Comment: Thanks, do you known names of dylibs for others?

Comment: they have something like IAPFree, IAPCrazy and you can check theme if you have a jailbreak download those tweaks then reverse it

Comment: @iMokhles, it is easy to break! Just need to rename LocalIAPStore.dylib to any other name like  LocalIStore.dylib

Comment: So server side check detect paths from remote list